# Load parent and its child records in single LINQ statement

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, eager-loading

I know this could easily be done in two hits to the database, but I've been experimenting with a single LINQ statement to load an order by ID and it's order items, translating them to ViewModel objects at the same time:

```
var query = from orderLine in db.PurchaseOrderLines
            where orderLine.PurchaseOrderId == id
            orderby orderLine.Id
            group orderLine by orderLine.PurchaseOrder into grouped
            select new PurchaseOrderViewModel
            {
                Id = grouped.Key.Id,
                PlacedDateTime = grouped.Key.PlacedDateTime,
                Reference = grouped.Key.OrderReference,
                StatusId = grouped.Key.PurchaseOrderStatusId,
                Status = grouped.Key.PurchaseOrderStatus.Description,
                Supplier = grouped.Key.Supplier.Name,
                SupplierId = grouped.Key.SupplierId,
                OrderLines = grouped.Select(row => new PurchaseOrderLineViewModel
                {
                    Id = row.Id,
                    PartNumber = row.Product.PartNumber,
                    ProductDescription = row.Product.Description,
                    Quantity = row.Quantity
                })
            };
```

However, the Type of `query` is `System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery<...PurchaseOrderViewModel>`, and trying to iterate the results throws an exception:

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Sequence contains no elements
  Source=System.Core
  StackTrace:
       at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.<GetElementFunction>b__3[TResult](IEnumerable`1 sequence)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.ExecuteSingle[TResult](IEnumerable`1 query, Expression queryRoot)
       at System.Data.Objects.ELinq.ObjectQueryProvider.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute[S](Expression expression)
       at System.Linq.Queryable.Single[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)
       at MyApp.Controllers.PurchaseOrderController.Details(Int32 id) in E:\Code\WCs\MyApp\MyApp\Controllers\PurchaseOrderController.cs:line 69
       at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
       at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass15.<InvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__12()
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilter(IActionFilter filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation)
  InnerException:
```

What am I doing wrong? Am I making a mistake to even attempt this?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options to force eager loading in LINQ-to-SQL.  Without knowing how you're executing your query or whether you're implementing paging and so on, it's hard to say.

The first thing I'd try (still inside your existing query) is simply forcing the `OrderLines` to a new list when the query is executed, like so:

```
OrderLines = grouped.Select(row => new PurchaseOrderLineViewModel
{
    Id = row.Id,
    PartNumber = row.Product.PartNumber,
    ProductDescription = row.Product.Description,
    Quantity = row.Quantity
}).ToList()
```

If this works, it's simple.

The alternative is to use the `DataLoadOptions` class. This is the usual way of implementing eager loading in LINQ-to-SQL.

```
var loadOptions = new DataLoadOptions();
loadOptions.LoadWith<PurchaseOrder>(p => p.PurchaseOrderLines);
db.LoadOptions = loadOptions;
```

The only catch is that you need to set the LoadOptions property of your datacontext before using the context.  This shouldn't be a problem if you're using the context in the recommended manner (short term, instance per operation), but that usage pattern doesn't seem to be as prevalent as intended.  If you create a datacontext and pass it around or hang on to it, then this might cause you problems.